# Loop through children of current node in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Suppose I have a specific table selected in TinyMCE, like this:

```
    var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    var selection = ed.selection.getContent();
    var element = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'table');
```

How do I loop through the `tr` elements inside this?

I suspect one of these methods might be relevant, but I'm so new to classes, I'm having trouble understanding how to apply them:

**TinyMCE select():** http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.select

**TinyMCE getAll():** http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.html.Node.getAll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may loop through any node in tinymce like a regular html node because they are in fact regular html nodes.

So this will suffice:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
var element = ed.dom.getParent(ed.selection.getNode(), 'table');

var child = element.firstChild;
while(child){
    if(child.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'tr'){
        //do your stuff here
    }
    child = child.nextSibling;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `var element` has property `childNodes`? It's an array of immediate child elements. Each of those will further have properties, where you would be interested in `nodeName`. Make a recursive function to search (each node further has `childNodes`), until you find that `nodeName=="TR"`.

BTW, this would be a lot easier with jQuery, if you're interested.

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_methods.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/dom_nodes_info.asp